# Play migration from 2.0.4 to 2.1.1, sbt error

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I seem to keep running into issues when I'm trying to upgrade from play 2.0.4 to 2.1.1.  I followed everything on the migration guide.  First it kept complaining about my proxy.  I think I finally got around it by adding -DhttpProxyHost, User, etc when I run play clean.  Now I ran into THIS issue.  I found a few people with similar issues but I don't think there is a clear solution on how to fix this. Any help will be appreciated!!!!

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt_2.9.1 0.12.2 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.12.2

    ==== local: tried

      /Users/wlam/Dev/play/play-2.0.2/framework/../repository/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.12.2/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven2 Local: tried

      file:///Users/wlam/.m2/repository/org/scala-sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.12.2/sbt_2.9.1-0.12.2.pom

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.12.2/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.12.2/sbt_2.9.1-0.12.2.pom

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.12.2: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.12.2: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /Users/wlam/Dev/play/play-2.0.2/framework/sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.12.2
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to install Play 2.1 and use it to launch your project. Currently you are running 2.0.2 which uses Scala 2.9, while Play 2.1 is only available for Scala 2.10.

sbt 0.12.2 seems to be only available with Scala 2.9.2, not 2.9.1.